# Filter out rows when condition is met with dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, case-when

How to filter out rows in one column when condition is met in another column for different groups?

For example:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <-tribble(
   ~group, ~var1, ~var2,
  "a", 0, 0,
  "a", 1, 0,
  "a",1, 0,
  "a",0, 1,
  "a", 1, 0,
  "b", 1, 0,
  "b", 0, 1,
  "b", 1, 0,
  "b", 0, 1)
```

I want to allow ones in `var1` only after having the first `1` in `var2`. Therefore, in this example, I would like to get:

```
group  var1  var2
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 a         0     0
 a         0     1
 a         1     0
 b         0     1
 b         1     0
 b         0     1
```

I can identify from where I want to start filtering the data, but don't know exactly how to proceed:

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(var2,group) %>% 
  mutate(test = case_when(row_number() == 1 & var2 == 1 ~ "exclude_previous_rows",
                         T ~ "n"))
```

I'm sure there is a simple way to do this with dplyr, but couldn't find it so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a cumulative sum. I think this is what you want:

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(cumsum(var2 == 1) > 0)
# # A tibble: 5 x 3
# # Groups:   group [2]
#   group  var1  var2
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a         0     1
# 2 a         1     0
# 3 b         0     1
# 4 b         1     0
# 5 b         0     1
```

This will keep all rows including and after the first `1` in `var2`, by group. I'm not really sure what you mean by *"I want to allow ones in var1"* - your code seems to ignore `var1`, and mine follows suit.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! 

By *"I want to allow ones in var1"* I meant that there should be ```1``` in ```var1``` only after having ```1``` in ```var2```, which is what ```cumsum``` did. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, but *"there should be 1 in var1 only after having 1 in var2"* makes it sound like you want to keep 0s in `var1` before there is a `1` in `var2`, but there's nothing in your code to handle that case. I would think something like `filter(cumsum(var2 == 1) > 0 | var1 != 1)`. (Perhaps you trust in your data that that can't happen.)

Comment: True! I also have double 0s I want to keep in the dataframe. Your solution using ```... | var1 !=1)``` is the best one. I edited my example to fulfill this condition. Could you please edit your answer as well? Cheers!

Comment: I'm glad the comment helped, but in general you should avoid editing the question *after* receiving working answers... "moving the goalposts" as it were.

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[, .I[cumsum(var2 == 1) > 0], group]$V1]
```